# MySQL запрос для выбора нескольких значений по id через запятую

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы — например, `table1` и `table2`. Одно из полей первой таблицы - `x` - ссылается на поля второй таблицы и состоит из `id` строк второй таблицы, перечисленных через запятую.

[image]

Задача: составить MySQL запрос таким образом, чтобы вместо номеров `id` строк второй были значения поля `y` соответственных полей, то есть условно результат должен быть таковым:

[image]

Теоритечески, в реализации пригодятся операторы/функции [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) и какое-то хитрое обьединение, реализацию которого я придумать не смог.

Comment: У вас **НЕ** [первая нормальная форма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Первая_нормальная_форма). всякие шаманства со split'ами и прочие танцы к sql отношения не имеет. Если такая шляпа уже реализована, то лучше продолжать мучиться с ней в php, субд не виновата, не обижайте ее.

Comment: Сочувствую ТС - такие оксюмороны регулярно случаются у проектировщиков с кривыми лапками. Здесь только хардкор и только решать на стороне клиента через похапэ или писать хранимку на стороне сервака.

Comment: Юрий, увы, задача составлена не мной, и идея не в "лучшем" решении, а в решении задачи в рамках данных условий, даже если они противоречят правильности, здравому смыслу и прочьим штукам.

Comment: Вообще у меня подозрения, что человек просто малознаком с базами данных, именно с проектированием, потому такие вопросы задает. По хорошему тут даже если это сделал не автор вопроса, то переделать можно было бы просто, чтобы все было по-человечески, вернее по-программистки))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, group_concat(y) from (
select t1.id, find_in_set(t2.id, t1.x) n,t2.y from table2 t2, table1 t1
) X
where n<>0
group by id;
```

Comment: Так будет быстрее:

    select t1.id, group_concat(t2.y)
    from tab1 t1
      join tab2 t2 on find_in_set(t2.id, t1.x)>0
    group by t1.id;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06b53/3

Comment: Возможно ли модифицировать запрос так, чтобы поля, у которых нет вовсе ничего в поле `x`, тоже входили в результат? Увы, сейчас они просто игнорируются.

Comment: @Crasher, [left join](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad06e/2)

Answer (score 2):

Ну, выбираете из второй таблицы все записи (я так подозреваю, их немного должно быть), загоняете в массив (id=>value). Затем делаете выборку из первой и делаете поиск с подстановкой по списку для каждой записи. Аналогично было бы в sql, с ограничениями по работе со строками, конвертации значений и т.д. Просто пользы в использовании sql тут никакой. Все равно это костыли.
Лучше было бы приложить усилия к рефакторингу, сделать нормальную структуру и использовать в итоге базу по назначению.

Answer (score 2):

Про структуру, какую тут все имеют в виду. Табличка, где строками указаны через запятую айдишники другой таблички, должна быть переделана под таблицу соответствий, то есть добавить ключи/индекс, сделать третью дополнительную колонку id, tab2tab, index / у вас получится табличка, где, например, первая строка (с текстом '1,2,3') превратится в три строки: 1-1 1-2 1-3. Навеки ваш КО

Comment: Спасибо за описание, возможно, оно будет полезно для тех, кто найдёт этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность использовать php или найти аналог на MySQL, то существует функция explode(), которая возвращает массив значений переменной, разделённой каким-либо символом.
Например:

```
$str = "user:date:city";
$A = explode(":" $str);
```

В массиве А будут элементы "user", " date" и "city".